# Program slows down but the numbers being calculated get smaller

Tags: java, algorithm, division, biginteger

I'm creating a custom implementation of Java's `BigInteger` class, with subsequent methods:

- multiply
- divide,
- add
- subtract.

I have a problem with division.

```
private BigInt createQuotient (BigInt aNumber, BigInt other){
    BigInt dividend = new BigInt(aNumber.toString());
    BigInt divisor = new BigInt(other.toString());
    dividend.isNegative = false;
    divisor.isNegative = false;
    BigInt finalQoutient = new BigInt("0");
    BigInt one = new BigInt("1");

    while(compareBigInts(dividend, divisor) == 1) {
            BigInt two = one;
            BigInt lastTwo = new BigInt("0");
            BigInt temp = divisor;
            BigInt lastTemp = new BigInt("0");
        while(compareBigInts(dividend, temp) == 1) {
                lastTwo = two;
                lastTemp = temp;

                if (two == one) {
                        two = two.add(one);
                }
                else{
                        two = two.add(two);
                }
                temp = divisor.multiply(two);

        }

        finalQoutient = finalQoutient.add(lastTwo);
        dividend = dividend.subtract(lastTemp);


}
finalQoutient = finalQoutient.add(one);
return finalQoutient;
}
```

Code represents this algorithm:

Let's say 100 is our dividend and 5 is our divisor with 20 being our final quotient.

```
while dividend > divisor, do:

2^0 * 5 = 5 which is less than our dividend, so we increment two ;  
2^1 * 5 = 10 which is less than our dividend, so we increment two ;  
2^2 * 5 = 20 which is less than our dividend, so we increment two ;  
2^3 * 5 = 40 which is less than our dividend, so we increment two ;  
2^4 * 5 = 80 which is less than our dividend, so we increment two ; (lastTemp)  
2^4 * 5 = 160 which is greater than our dividend, so we save the value before this one ; (temp)
```

We then take that saved value and remove it from the dividend, making it                      smaller. We simultaneously take that value and add it to a variable each time a loop is completed.

We do this until the dividend gets to be smaller than the divisor, at which point we simply return the variable that stored added lastTemp for each loop.

With that in mind, my program works for smaller numbers but becomes extremely slow as `aNumber` becomes larger. Since all my variables are shrinking I would expect each pass to be faster, however my program gets slower.

Why is this?

Full `BigInt` class.

https://github.com/collinarnett/big-int/blob/master/BigInt.java

Comment: Do you know what is [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? You have n*n Algorithm!

Comment: The inner while loop is operating on a smaller number (since dividend shrinks) each time the outer while loop is run, therefore it should run faster with each pass of the outer while loop. @Gatusko

Comment: how does compare work? When the numerator is bigger, does it return 1?

Comment: @fileyfood500 Compare returns 1 when the numerator is greater than the denominator, -1 when the denominator is greater than the numerator and 0 when they are equal.

Comment: Looking at compare, it seems like the denominator must have fewer digits than the numerator (or the same), but maybe I'm misreading something or it's not relevant here

Comment: @fileyfood500 The code works, but becomes extremely slow once larger numbers are introduced. All numbers are also the same length since the method `addZerosIfNeeded` is called before the check.

Comment: You're finding the point where shifting the denominator to the left causes it to be greater than the numerator in a _very_ expensive way. Think about how you can determine the required shift without actually shifting and comparing the entire result.

Comment: @Gene This would still mean that my program would be the slowest right at the start, whereas the opposite is true is practice.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that you'd expect that as `aNumber` grows, your program becomes faster?

Comment: No, I am specifically referring to as `createQuoteint` processes `dividend` it should get faster, since `dividend` shrinks. @yeputons

Comment: @CollinArnett That makes sense, so what is your exact question/confusion? Each next pass is becoming slightly faster than the previous, but there are still a lot of passes for big numbers, so total running time grows significantly.

Comment: @yeputons The program does not run faster after each pass in practice.

Comment: @CollinArnett how have you measured it? Please add measuring code, measuring steps and results to the question.

Comment: Just by printing out any of the dynamic variables in the method you can see the calculations being done slower and slower. @yeputons

Comment: Btw, is `two == one` a bug? In Java `==` does not compare object's content at all (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, sizes of `dividend.bigNum.size()` and `temp.bigNum.size()` grow exponentially on each iteration. I've added

```
System.out.println(dividend + " " + temp + "; sizes are " + dividend.bigNum.size() + " " + temp.bigNum.size());
```

right before your innermost `while` loop and got the following:

```
366000000000 36; sizes are 12 12
56762354688 36; sizes are 24 24
18107649024 36; sizes are 48 48
8443972608 36; sizes are 96 96
3612134400 36; sizes are 192 192
1196215296 36; sizes are 384 384
592235520 36; sizes are 768 768
290245632 36; sizes are 1536 1536
139250688 36; sizes are 3072 3072
```

That happens in part because your `BigInt(String)` does not truncate heading zeros (probably should be done in `createArrayList`) and in part because they're doubled by `createProduct` in both arguments.

My recommendation for the future is to debug this issue the same way as if it were a correctness issue: print variable sizes, look at expected sizes, look at real values. Also, you can use profiler.

Comment: Yes this fixed my issue. I've added a method `removeZeros` that I've put at the end of these methods. Thank you so much.